# Accessing LogCat from Android via Python

Tags: android, python, events, logcat, android-logcat

Is it possible to read information being sent over LogCat in python?

I have a program that is written in java.
Every draw frame it sends tag:"Fps: " message: number
I would like this message to fire an event that I can catch in my python script so I can draw a fps-meter.

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html). The following code was adapted from [Stefaan Lippens](http://stefaanlippens.net/python-asynchronous-subprocess-pipe-reading)

```
import Queue
import subprocess
import threading


class AsynchronousFileReader(threading.Thread):
    '''
    Helper class to implement asynchronous reading of a file
    in a separate thread. Pushes read lines on a queue to
    be consumed in another thread.
    '''

    def __init__(self, fd, queue):
        assert isinstance(queue, Queue.Queue)
        assert callable(fd.readline)
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._fd = fd
        self._queue = queue

    def run(self):
        '''The body of the tread: read lines and put them on the queue.'''
        for line in iter(self._fd.readline, ''):
            self._queue.put(line)

    def eof(self):
        '''Check whether there is no more content to expect.'''
        return not self.is_alive() and self._queue.empty()


# You'll need to add any command line arguments here.
process = subprocess.Popen(["logcat"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Launch the asynchronous readers of the process' stdout.
stdout_queue = Queue.Queue()
stdout_reader = AsynchronousFileReader(process.stdout, stdout_queue)
stdout_reader.start()

# Check the queues if we received some output (until there is nothing more to get).
while not stdout_reader.eof():
    while not stdout_queue.empty():
        line = stdout_queue.get()
        if is_fps_line(line):
            update_fps(line)
```

Of course, you'll need to write the `is_fps_line` and `update_fps` functions yourself.

Comment: Cool, Thanks man! :D Was exaaactly what I was looking for :))))

Comment: doesnt work though xD gives this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Eclipse Workspace\ThirdWorkspace\test.pydev\src\FpsMeter.py", line 116, in <module>
    process = subprocess.Popen(["logcat"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: The line marked contains this code: process = subprocess.Popen(["logcat"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: This code assumes that logcat is on your path. If it isn't on your runtime path, then you need to provide the full path for logcat (e.g. "C:\Program Files\...\logcat") in replace of the "logcat" string.

Comment: logcat doesnt exist in the android dir. You can launch android via "adb logcat" in console though... Event providing the full path  C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\logcat it doesnt work.

Comment: If adb is on your path then then you can use `process = subprocess.Popen(["adb", "logcat"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: This one works.. but can someone tell me how can I stop collecting the logs when a particular condition is met?

Comment: Did you try with SIGTERM,? or at least subprocess.kill() ?? Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true and https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 6):

I would redirect `adb logcat` to your python script. This would look like:

```
$ adb logcat | python yourscript.py
```

Now you can read from logcat on [sys.stdin](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) and parse it however you like.